# AWS EFS filsystem mounting issue via anislbe-playbook

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-efs

we installed efs utility and configured the EFS filesystem with EFS Mount points with in the VPC.
Added the entry in /etc/fstab for permanent mount like below.

```
echo "mount fs-xxxxxxx /mnt/efs efs tls,_netdev 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
```

after this when i manually run the `mount -a -t efs defaults` - it is working fine file system got mounted successfully without any issue.

But when i try to invoke the same thing from ansible mount module like below

```
- name: Mount up efs
  mount:
    path: /mnt/efs
    src: fs-xxxxxxxx
    fstype: efs
    opts: tls
    state: mounted
  become: true
  become_method: pbrun
  become_user: root
```

Note: Ansible is running as root privilaged user on the target host.

**Expected Result:**
EFS filesystem should get mounted without any issue.

**Actual Result:**
We are getting error in ansible saying like

```
Error:
only root can run mount.efs
```

when i start debugging the issue i see the entry in init.py for efs
https://github.com/aws/efs-utils/blob/555154b79572cd2a9f63782cac4c1062eb9b1ebd/src/mount_efs/init.py

we are validating the user with getpass python module but some how even i am using the become in the ansible it is not help me to get ride of this error.

Could you please anyone help me to resolve tis issue

Answer (score 1):

Either the [fstype is nfs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/wt1-test.html#wt1-mount-fs-and-test) or you may need to [install the EFS Mount Helper](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/mounting-fs.html#mounting-fs-mount-helper).